# How do I determine the of a CTLine following a CTLine

Tags: ios, core-text

I have a CTLine and I can get the typographic bounds, but that does not tell me how much space there will be after this line and before the next.

Do I have to go through the paragraph styles and determine the maximum paragraph spacing after this line through that, or is there a simpler approach to determine the offset one would use with CTTypesetterCreateLineWithOffset?

Comment: Is your title missing a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: there is no public CoreText function that calculates this. You have to calculate it yourself unforunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CTFramesetter` to get a `CTFrame` from your attributed string, then use `CTFrameGetLineOrigins()` to pull out the vertical spacing.